# Any way to get Eclipse to always use common VM args for running JUnit tests?

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

Anyone know how to get Eclipse to use a set of default VM args? I'm getting fed up of constantly having to specify these manually every time I run a specific package, class or method within my otherwise smoothly-running test suite.

Using JUnit 4, Eclipse 3.5.

Rationale: some tests are integration tests verifying operations with large input sets so it's tedious to have to keep putting in:

```
-Xms256m -Xmx512m
```

If there's something, e.g. in Eclipse prefs, where I can specify this once and for all I'd be very grateful!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you run your tests in a separate JRE (the default, I think) then you can go to Installed JREs and specify default VM arguments for it there, as in the screenshot below (the orange buttons indicate what I clicked to access the dialog below it).

If you run your tests in the same JRE as the workspace, then the solution is to edit your eclipse.ini file and put the arguments there.

[image: Screenshot of JRE VM arguments]

Comment: Looks promising I'll give it a go

Comment: Keep in mind that this would affect all run targets that use this JVM, e.g., things other than JUnit tests.

Answer (score 0):

you can try in eclipse.ini file

http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini